# how did the demultiplexer being notified when OP_ACCEPT event happened

Tags: java, linux, select, nio

The demultiplexer could monitor many socket fds events  with this method :

`int select (int n, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);`

from the parameters , there are read events, write events and exception event , but where is the accept event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a read event on ServerSocket. Manual page for `select(2)`:

> In order to be notified of incoming connections on a socket, you can use select(2) or poll(2).   A  readable  event  will  be
>          delivered  when  a  new connection is attempted and you may then call accept() to get a socket for that connection.

Comment: You can't use single socket in server and client modes simultaneously. After you call `listen()` on a socket, it becomes server socket and may only be used for accepting remote clients. If you then call `connect()` on the same socket, it will return EISCONN ("already connected") error.

Comment: Not it won't. It isn't already connected. It will probably return EINVAL.